# How to use blob data type to save base64(image) in Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, base64, blob, cql

How to use blob data type to save base64(image) in Cassandra ?

This is my create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xadvisor.session ( user_id varchar, images set <blob>, PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO xadvisor.session ( user_id , images) VALUES ('XAU1', {\'"+base64+"\'});
```

base64 is achieved from my local picture:

```
var base64 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../tmp/assets/images_png/capture00001.png'), 'base64');
```

I got the error like this: 
`{"name":"ResponseError","stack":"Error: Invalid set literal for images: value 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABHQAAAHuCAYAAAD+yVs........`

Thank you for you attention and suggestions in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In the nodejs driver from datastax a blob is equal to a buffer, see here:
http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/datatypes/

But if you intend to use base64 - you are simply handling some text, no need to use a blob at all.

Reminder: Keep 'blob' small enough for performance (single digit megabytes).

Update: Oh I overlooked the set.

Are you getting any errors? Then please provide them as well.

> Sets are limited in CQL - a value has to be smaller than 64kb.
>   Collection (Set): collection limit: ~2 billion (231); values size:
>   65535 (216-1)

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

Update:

typeAsBlob() might be your friend (see http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html) - e.g. textAsBlob():

```
cqlsh:demo> DESCRIBE blob ;

CREATE TABLE demo.blob (
    user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    payload blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO blob (user_id, payload) VALUES ('demo_user','YXNsa2RramFzZAo=');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (YXNsa2RramFzZAo=) for "payload" of type blob"
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO blob (user_id, payload) VALUES ('demo_user',textAsblob('YXNsa2RramFzZAo='));
cqlsh:demo> SELECT * FROM blob ;

 user_id   | payload
-----------+------------------------------------
 demo_user | 0x59584e7361325272616d467a5a416f3d

(1 rows)
cqlsh:demo>
```

As a base64 encoded image is simply a string you could use also text. And for storing your images, build a seperate table which holds them, user_id as partition key and an unique identifier (maybe a hash) as clustering column:

```
cqlsh> USE demo ;
cqlsh:demo> DESCRIBE TABLE demo.images ;

CREATE TABLE demo.images (
    user_id text,
    image_id text,
    image_payload text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, image_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (image_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO demo.images (user_id, image_id, image_payload) VALUES ('demo_user1', 'img000.png', 'YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO demo.images (user_id, image_id, image_payload) VALUES ('demo_user1', 'img002.png', 'YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO demo.images (user_id, image_id, image_payload) VALUES ('demo_user1', 'img017.png', 'YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO demo.images (user_id, image_id, image_payload) VALUES ('demo_user2', 'img001.png', 'YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=');
cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO demo.images (user_id, image_id, image_payload) VALUES ('demo_user2', 'img002.png', 'YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=');
cqlsh:demo> SELECT image_id, image_payload FROM demo.images WHERE user_id = 'demo_user1';

 image_id   | image_payload
------------+----------------------
 img000.png | YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=
 img002.png | YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=
 img017.png | YWRsa2tqYXNkaGpzZAo=

(3 rows)
cqlsh:demo>
```

Comment: I re-edit my question and add the errors I got from console. I got to realize that set may not be a proper choice for me to use in this context considering the storage limit. In this case, I need to store many images in column_name (images), can you suggest me an alternative way to realize this ?